# Why am I getting a JavaScript error from this code?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>An app</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <p id='namespace'> Namelist </p>
    <button id="display" type="button">Display numbers</button></br>
    <button id="likebutton" type="button">Like</button>
    <button id="dislikebutton" type="button">Dislike</button>

  </body>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var names = ['Hannah', 'Lucy', 'Brenda', 'Lauren', 'Mary'];
  var liked = [];
  var disliked = [];



    function showName(){
      var name = names[0];
      if (!name){
        name = 'Out of people';
      }
      document.getElementById('namespace').innerHTML = name;
    }
    function like(){
      liked.push(names[0]);
      names.splice(0, 1);
      showName();
    }
    function dislike(){
      disliked.push(names[0]);
      names.splice(0, 1);
      showName();
    }

    showName();
    document.getElementById('likeButton').onclick = like;
    document.getElementById('dislikeButton').onclick = dislike;

 });
  </script>
</html>
```

The current error is saying this: `uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null`

I have googled this error and it seems to be something regarding the dom and maybe how elements have not fully loaded onto a page or something?

I want the solution to have different names popping up after the user has clicked the like or dislike button. Then at the end of the array, the text will display no more people.

Comment: `likeButton` and `dislikeButton` should be complete small case, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button's id is `likebutton` and you are getting it by `likeButton`

Change

```
document.getElementById('likeButton').onclick = like;
```

To

```
document.getElementById('likebutton').onclick = like;
```

Same is the case for `dislikebutton`.

Comment: thanks, so annoying to miss that. do you know how i can then look at the arrays in the console?? i have the console open and started typing liked.length but it told me liked is not defined?

Comment: You can write `debugger;` before the line which you want to inspect in console to see the values of array or anything you want. Also don't forget to mark the answer as accepted answer.